# Firebase v9 JS SDK secure to use on client side?

Tags: reactjs, database, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, frontend

I am working on a mobile app, where users have complex profiles and can chat to each other. So right now I am using  firebase's onSnapshot() listener in the frontend code to get the real-time data ASAP. I am thinking whether its secure enough? Would it be better to move it to the backend server? Than fetching real-time would be way more complex I guess. Could you tell me what are the dangers of keeping these listeners on frontend? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Could you tell me what are the dangers of keeping these listeners on
> frontend?

The standard way for securing your database (as well as Cloud Storage buckets) is by using [Security Rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started).

In particular the documentation explains that:

> Every database request from a Cloud Firestore mobile/web client
> library is evaluated against your security rules before reading or
> writing any data. If the rules deny access to any of the specified
> document paths, the entire request fails.

This evaluation is totally independent from the way you query the database: Whether you query it via a realtime listener or via a one time fetch (using one of the `get()` methods) the database request is evaluated against your security rules.

So, in conclusion, if you use Security Rules, there is no "danger" to use some realtime listeners.

---

> I am thinking whether its secure enough? Would it be better to move it
> to the backend server?

Based on the details you share in your question there is no reason, IMO, to switch to a back-end approach (like [using Cloud Functions to read the database](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/should-i-query-my-firebase-database-directly-or-use-cloud-functions-fbb3cd14118c)). One reason could be that your security logic is too complex to be implemented with the security rules language/model. But note that you can build complex logic in Security Rules, for example by basing them on [Custom Claims](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims) or [other Firestore documents](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#access_other_documents).